# Is it possible to customize the default Layout Settings in Content Builder for template based emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to customize the default Layout Settings. 
[image]

Comment: I believe this can only be done by creating a custom HTML template in CB - which would then completely remove this tab when editing/creating an email using this template.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but we are in discovery for a new feature that allows for block/layout customization, which includes defining your own default settings.